# React-Admin: How to redirect to <Dashboard> when authenticated through custom <Login> page

Tags: react-admin

`react-admin` loads the `<Dashboard>` at the base `"/"`. And for that reason, the custom  page never opens by default because the `<Admin>` always routes to the dashboard.

I've implemented `<PrivateRoutes>` to handle `authentication` and it's a success.
The `<Login>` page is loaded by default, and upon authentication, it routes to dashboard.

**Challenge:** This process breaks the functionality of Sidebar `<links>`, like "Users".

```js
// CustomRoutes.js
export default [
  <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} noLayout />,
  <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} noLayout />,
  <Route exact path="/confirm-password" component={ConfirmForgotPassword} noLayout />,
  <PrivateRoute path="/" loggedIn={localStorage.getItem("access_token")} component={dashboard} />
];
```

And then...

```
// PrivateRoute.js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ path, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("access_token");

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={props => isLoggedIn 
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Here's how it looks within the main `<App>`

```js
// App.js
const App = () => (
  <Admin
    theme={myTheme}
    dashboard={dashboard}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    customRoutes={customRoutes}
    loginPage={LoginPage}
    logoutButton={LogoutButton}
    forgotPassword={ForgotPassword}
  >
    <Resource name="users" list={UserList} create={UserCreate} show={UserShow} icon={UserIcon} />
  </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

**Please note** that the `<resource>` "users" is not working.
Do I need to add custom route for that too?

Answer (score 0):

> Alright, let's debug this step-by-step:

We can take advantage of `react-admin` directly to handle the `authentication` via the `authProvider`.

- Once you include the `authProvider`, `react-admin`enables a new page on the `/login` 
  route,
   which displays a `<Login>` form asking for username and password.
- You can definitely customize that login page (as I assume you did), 
  and I advise that you avoid using a `<PrivateRoute>` since the `authProvider` redirects all users who aren't yet authenticated to `/login`.
- Kindly note that `<Admin>` creates an application with its own state, routing, and controller logic.
  In your code, you added `forgotPassword` which is not a `prop` accepted by `<Admin`.

```js
<admin
   // remove this...
-  forgotPassword={ForgotPassword}
>
```

I wonder exactly what error you get in this case, but this is the main bug.